# Dynamically find field value from Map

Tags: dynamic-apex

Currently I'm looping through values, based on the loop # I want to be able to get different field values.

**Example:**

```
Integer years = 1;
for(Integer i = 1; i <= formYears; i++){
String fieldName = 'year_'+i+'__c';
Decimal increase = map.get(key).fieldName;//Here is the issue, can't use String! years = years + 1;
}
```

Is this possible?  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the item you are accessing from your map is an sObject, you can get the value of a field thusly:

```
// Create something we can then query
Account acc = new Account(Name='Test Account');
// Access the Name field 
System.debug(acc.get('Name'));
```

I believe this will work with Custom Objects, and Custom Fields, but not with inner classes. However, if you are using an inner class then you have control of the code so could do things differently :)

So for your specific case you'd do something like

```
Integer years = 1;
for(Integer i = 1; i <= formYears; i++){
    String fieldName = 'year_'+i+'__c';
    Decimal increase = map.get(key).get(fieldName); 
    years = years + 1;
}
```

Comment: You are correct, `.get(<field api name>)` works with any SObject (standard or custom), and any field (standard or custom) on an SObject. The exception to this may be things like `Address` and `Geolocation` compound fields (so `myAccount.get('BillingAddress') may not work, you'd need to grab the individual components instead, i.e. `myAccount.get(`BillingStreet')`, `myAccount.get('BillingCity')`, etc...)

Comment: Thanks TomB, worked like a charm.  I had to add Double.ValueOf(map.get(key).get(fieldName)); to finalize.

Comment: You're welcome - happy to help